# How to Schedule my windows service?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I created 4 wcf services.
I want to create a windows service with first WCF service will run every one minute and 2 nd service will run after 5 minutes and 3rd service will run every 5 minutes and 4th service will run continuously 30 minutes.The total time of this service is 30minutes.

After 30 minutes the service will reset and run again.

Can any body help me to get this solution..............

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you need a scheduler - a good one for .net applications is Quartz.NET ( http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/ )

it is very flexible in how you store the schedule specification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows Task Scheduler for startup but you have to code the runtime duration by your self in your code.

Answer (score 0):

when your service starts store the start time in a variable and check if the time difference is grater than 30 mins then reset the timer.